# Trouble getting pgAmin4 to work on Fedora 28

Tags: fedora

I have installed pgAdmin4 through `dnf`. It showed some error that Qt application has an error related to some tray icon not present. On Arch linux forum, I found that someone solved it by installing Gnome extension `TopIcons Plus` and so did I.

Now when I run the pgAdmin4 from a terminal using `pgadmin4` I get an error

```
                      Fatal Error
An error occurred initialising the application server

Failed to launch application server, server thread exiting.

                                          _______________
                                         |______OK_______|
```

There were few other issues in installation but that got solved easily. I have reached a dead end where [the SoF link mentions this issue should not arrive in *nix systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968302/postgressql-failed-to-launch-application-server-server-thread-existing-on-windo#45561847)

Any help to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the PostgreSQL mailing thread, and blog post on http://people.planetpostgresql.org I found the solution.

While installing the pgAdmin4 on Fedora 28 the `dnf` installation is fine but it misses fetching one dependency namely `python3-flask-babelex`. Install this dependency and you will be good to go.

```
[root@localhost /]$ dnf install python3-flask-babelex
```